# how to display only subcategory on the category page without using the taxonomy-product_cat page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```html
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying products in a product category. Simply includes the archive template
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see      http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package  WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}


wc_get_template( 'archive-category.php' );
```

i am developing a E-commerce website in that i want to show only subcategories with their image and name and then after clicking on the subcategory name it should visit to the subcategory products page without affecting the taxonomy-product_cat page what to do please anyone can help ?
it is my code - both taxonomy-product_cat.php and archive-category.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see      http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author   WooThemes
 * @package  WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header(); ?>
 
  
  
  
  <div class="container-fluid"><div class="row">
  
  
  
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
  
 <?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
  $category_name = $term->name;
    $category_id = $term->term_id;
 
  $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
  $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail); ?>
  
 
  
  
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <?php echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$image.'">'; ?>
        <div class="overlay">
           <h2><?php  echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category_id ) . '">' .  $category_name . '</a>';  ?></h2>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
  
  
  
  
  

 <?php }


 ?>
 
 </div></div></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes i added 1 new page name archive-category.php on that page i have the code which show subcategories with their names and images but as the taxonomy-product_cat uses - wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' ); so when i replace the archive-product.php on taxonomy-product_cat.php by archive-category.php then it shows the subcategories on the category page but when clicking on sub-category it again lands on archive-category.php

Comment: Please post your code in your question. So it is easy for anyone to detect the problem :)

Comment: this can be handled in product category settings [see here](http://i.imgur.com/v19rbQj.png)

Comment: thanks @M.Doye it works perfect thanks alot :)